# SOAP C# Server with Java client null return

Tags: c#, java, web-services, soap

I would like to check SOAP interoperability between distinct platforms; I am a Java programmer and do not know C# in particular.

What have I managed to do in C#:

**The transfer Object**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot]
public class Pack
{
    private int id;
    private string name;

    public Pack()
    {   
    }

    public Pack(int anId, string aName)
    {
        this.id = anId;
        this.name = aName;
    }

    public void setId(int anId)
    {
        this.id = anId;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(string aName)
    {
        this.name = aName;
    }

    public string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**The Web Service**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class PackWS : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    private Dictionary<int, Pack> dictionary;

    public PackWS()
    {
        dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Pack>();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(String))]
    public String getName()
    {
        return "Goodbye world!";
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Pack))]
    public void addPackage(Pack package)
    {
       dictionary.Add(package.getId(), package);
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Pack))]
    public Pack getPackage(int id)
    {
        return dictionary[id];
    }
}
```

The project builds and publishes the wsdl at the specified URI. I have added a Java client part:

**The Transfer Object**:

```
package user;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Pack {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**The Interface:**

```
package user;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/",
        portName = "PackWSSoap",
        wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:57265/Service.asmx?wsdl",
        serviceName = "PackWS")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public interface PackWSSoap {
    void addPackage(Pack pack);
    Pack getPackage(int id);
    String getName();
}
```

**The Service**

```
package user;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class PackageClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:57265/Service.asmx?wsdl");
            QName qName = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "PackWS");

            Service service = Service.create(url, qName);

            PackWSSoap packWS = service.getPort(PackWSSoap.class);

            System.out.println(packWS.getName());//null here

            packWS.addPackage(getPack());//C# exception here

            System.out.println(packWS.getPackage(getPack().getId()));//unreachable 


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static Pack getPack() {
        return new Pack(){{
            setId(2);
            setName("name");
        }
        };
    }
}
```

When calling the `getName()` method, it should return a simple String, but it returns null. When trying to add a package by calling `addPackage(pack)` I receive an exception from C# on the client, in Java:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at PackWS.addPackage(Pack package) in f:\DS Projects\ds5\NET\App_Code\PackWS.cs:line 38
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:163)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:94)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:236)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:206)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:103)
    at $Proxy18.addPackage(Unknown Source)
    at user.PackageClient.main(PackageClient.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

I do not believe to be anything wrong with the communication since the exception is passed well; but I believe I did not add something to the .NET server. Any help would be appreciated and sorry for the long post.

Here is the **WSDL**:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<s:element name="getName">
<s:complexType/>
</s:element>
<s:element name="getNameResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="getNameResult" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="addPackage">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="package" nillable="true" type="tns:Pack"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="Pack"/>
<s:element name="addPackageResponse">
<s:complexType/>
</s:element>
<s:element name="getPackage">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="id" type="s:int"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="getPackageResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="getPackageResult" nillable="true" type="tns:Pack"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="getNameSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getName"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getNameSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getNameResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="addPackageSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:addPackage"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="addPackageSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:addPackageResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getPackageSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getPackage"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getPackageSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getPackageResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="PackWSSoap">
<wsdl:operation name="getName">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getNameSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getNameSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="addPackage">
<wsdl:input message="tns:addPackageSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:addPackageSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getPackage">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getPackageSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getPackageSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="PackWSSoap" type="tns:PackWSSoap">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="getName">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/getName" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="addPackage">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/addPackage" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getPackage">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/getPackage" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="PackWSSoap12" type="tns:PackWSSoap">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="getName">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/getName" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="addPackage">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/addPackage" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getPackage">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/getPackage" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="PackWS">
<wsdl:port name="PackWSSoap" binding="tns:PackWSSoap">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:57265/Service.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="PackWSSoap12" binding="tns:PackWSSoap12">
<soap12:address location="http://localhost:57265/Service.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Just a little suggestion, not solving your issue, just a good practice for later maintainance, in your WebService annotation, you are using a remote wsdl location, it would be better to use the local uri 
(example: WEB-INF/WebContent/wsdl/Service.wsdl)

Comment: looks like a problem in your wsdl. `xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"` says you are using soap 1.2. Your java client is SOAP 1.1 Try to generate client with `wsimport` tool, it usually show errors.

Comment: Your problem is NOT that the `String` you are receiving is not null. The C# web service is throwing the error. You should get the stack trace on the C# side to see where the NullReferenceException happens. Also, going here http://localhost:57265/Service.asmx from your browser should give you a form where you can invoke the WebMethods directly. You could use that to see if the exception occurs there, and what your stack trace is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Web services in .NET don't maintain session state between requests.  When you initialize the dictionary, it is only there for the duration of that particular request.  On subsequent requests, it's null again, hence the exception you're getting.

If you want to implement a service like this, using an object that persists between requests, you can use Application as a shared store.  It looks a little ugly because you have to type cast when you access it, though.

Initialization:

```
Application["dictionary"] = new Dictionary<int, Pack>();
```

Adding:

```
((Dictionary<int, Pack>)Application["dictionary"]).Add(package.getId(), package);
```

Reading:

```
return ((Dictionary<int, Pack>)Application["dictionary"])[id];
```

More information about the Application store - an instance of HttpApplicationState - is available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer; saving the info to a file seems the easiest way. Do you also know why I get null when calling      [WebMethod]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(String))]
    public String getName()
    {
        return "Goodbye world!";
    }

Comment: Did you re-deploy the service after updating the code to return just the string?  I just tried your updated code and got <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Goodbye world!</string>

Answer (score 2):

If it is not strictly necessary, I would never use soap. I would recommend you to use a REST web service putting in the body JSON objects.

Comment: I am aware that REST is better from most point of views, but this is for learning purposes...

Answer (score 1):

Where is your .asmx file (ASP.NET web service)?

The exception you are getting is from PackWS.cs:line 38 which should be getPackage() web method.

When I run PackageClient I get

```
Dec 22, 2012 7:13:50 AM org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromWSDL
INFO: Creating Service {http://tempuri.org/}PackWS from WSDL: http://10.0.1.32:49232/PackWS.asmx?wsdl
Dec 22, 2012 7:13:51 AM org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromWSDL
INFO: Creating Service {http://tempuri.org/}PackWS from WSDL: http://10.0.1.32:49232/PackWS.asmx?wsdl
Hello world!
```

And on the .NET web service I get

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232969
  Message=The given key was not present in the dictionary.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
       at PackWS.getPackage(Int32 id) in c:\Users\Vineet\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PackWS\PackWS\PackWS.asmx:line 39
  InnerException:
```

To fix that follow what Scott's mentioned above.

Checkout entire source for .NET web service at

https://github.com/firefoxNX/StackOverflow/tree/master/PackWS

and Java client at

https://github.com/firefoxNX/StackOverflow/tree/master/PackWSClient